# How to set root permission for all users?

Tags: permissions

I'm a beginner and I don't have any idea about how to give root permissions to all users, I've tried using `gpasswd -a sqeeph root` but the terminal  still displays `sqeeph@root`

Comment: Can you suggest why you would give root permissions to all users? Maybe some context? Or else it sounds a bit ridiculous.

Comment: You probably are stating a **[XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)**. What is broken now that could apparently be fixed by giving all user root permissions? Why would you want to do this? I'm sure what you are trying to achieve has a proper solution (and that making other users root is NOT proper, nor even a solution)

Answer (score 9):

First: The idea of giving `root` privileges to all users, whether being based upon a misunderstanding or risking that everybody could (possibly unwillingly) crash the whole system is about the most dangerous thing one could do.

There are different roles:

- **`root`** a.k.a `superuser`: Could do everything with the whole system AND everybody's
  data, e.g. delete other users too. There is a T-Shirt design with the slogan: »*I am root. If you see me laughing, you better have a backup*«
- **`user`**: Accounts via which people are allowed to use the system. To whatever extend they are allowed to e.g. install data, delete other users, delete essential parts of your system etc. depends on `root`
- **`sudo`**(ers): Certain accounts, often defined in `/etc/sudoers`, allowed to do certain stuff as `root` user. Again, `root` defines
  whoever is allowed to do stuff in her/his name

[image: http://xkcd.com/149/]
([source](https://xkcd.com/149/))

What I, personally, would recommend would be:

- Consider giving certain rights to certain users
- **OR** put certain accounts in one group with special permissions
- **OR** put special accounts you want to be allowed to possibly blow your system to kingdom come into the `sudo`ers file via editing `etc/sudoers`
  → [Here a manual from sudo.ws](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) about configuring `/etc/sudoers`

Again: Giving all your users a [Big Red Button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_red_button) would be interesting in a virtual machine and watching it going down the drain in all it's glory as one fumbles around. But one should not operate on an exposed heart with tools they possibly can't handle. Everything else would be suicidal. Leave `root` priviledges to `root`.

You might be interested in [→ this article on `sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) and also [→ this article on basic UNIX security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_security#Design_concepts).  And [another webcomic on `root`](https://xkcd.com/1200/) (here in the role of an [→ Admin(istrator)](https://xkcd.com/705/))

And a last one about being root and deleting other accounts: In the comic below, `root` deletes the account »*megan*« (`userdel --remove` would delete the `/home` directory and all its subdirectories (users personal data) of the »*megan*« account too (probably going off-topic but worth a read: → [A basic introduction to `userdel`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/removing-user-accounts.html))

[image]
([source](https://xkcd.com/215/))

Answer (score -2):

Giving `root` permission to all users is very dangerous, Despite if you need to give then add all users (whom you need to provide `root` permission) to `root` group.

Follow the steps.

```
usermod -G root savvy
usermod -G root user
```

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain about this, but I don't think that the root group actually gives users root permissions. I'd say that you have to change the uid of all users to 0 if you want to have them full root permissions, which of course is a bad idea too.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich even if it is configured this way: Don't make `root`s life harder than it already is! Thank you.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Each uid is unique within a system and uid zero is reserved for the root user. You cannot, by definition, grant that uid to other users. Traditionally, having zero uid allows you to bypass _all_ permission checks in the kernel. Root privileges can be provisioned to executables by setting the `setuid` bit (coarse grained, grants full privileges), or by using [POSIX capabilities](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5737) (fine-grained, grants certain privileges). Privileges can be provisioned to users via `sudo`.

Comment: @ThomasNyman But you absolutely can create multiple user accounts with the uid 0. They can all have different account names, different homes (and therefore different ssh authorized keys) and different shells, so there are situations where this makes sense.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I stand corrected, thank you for pointing this out. Apparently [FreeBSD uses this to provide an alternative superuser account to use with a non-standard shell](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/faq/security.html#TOOR-ACCOUNT). Using this for permission provisioning though, seems like a very bad idea.